# Write elf header in an output file

Tags: c, elf

I am trying to write an elf header in an output file.

I tried using fwrite and fputc, but when i compare the results with readelf -h, it doesn't give the results that i am expecting.

I figured out that maybe, i have to write the section header after the elf header might change up something, since i am not sure if that affects the -h option in any way possible or not.

```
char* data2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(data));
char* TableHs2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(*TableHs));
printf("sizeof(data2) = %ld\n",strlen(data2) );

FILE* resultat=fopen("SortieElf","w+");


memcpy(data2,&data,sizeof(data));
memcpy(TableHs2,TableHs,sizeof(*TableHs));
printf("memcpy succesfull\n");
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(data);i++)
{
    //printf("%c\n",data2[i] );
    fputc(data2[i],resultat);

}

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(TableHs);i++)
{
    //printf("%c\n",data2[i] );
    fputc(TableHs2[i],resultat);

}

//fwrite(&data,1,sizeof(data),resultat);
fclose(resultat);
```

Anything beyond "Version ABI" in the output of readelf -h is not correct.

Comment: Your first `printf` is going to have undefined behaviours as you're printing the output of the length of a random bit of memory - no NUL terminated string has been copied to at that point

Comment: Why do you copy the data _in memory_ to data2/TableHs2 at all? Why not just fputc from data/TableHs?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve code snippet. I'm pretty sure you elf header struct (variable data here) contains pointers. So obviously you will write the pointer value, not its content..

Comment: @Ctx putc needs a char, but i have a struct.

Comment: @Tezirg I use the Elf32_Ehdr type available in elf.h, it's elements doesn't contain any pointers. I believe that my code snippet is fine the way it is because it contains the only informations that you need to understand what i want to do, you can ask me for specefic explications.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of two thing:

1. With `fopen("SortieElf","w+")` you open the file in *text* mode
2. With `fputc(data2[i],resultat)` you write a *character*, which in text-mode might do some translation (most notable a character corresponding to a newline `'\n'` can be translated to carriage return-newline `"\r\n"` on some platforms).

The solution is two-fold: First you need to open the file in *binary* mode:

```
fopen("SortieElf","w+b")
```

Secondly, write the whole structure *as is* instead (no needing the temporary buffers) using [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite):

```
fwrite(&data, sizeof data, 1, resultat);
```

---

There are also other problems with your code, like for example using `sizeof` on a pointer which returns the size of the *pointer* and not the data it points to.

Comment: What you said makes sense, but strangely that still give the same output.

Comment: @TaguiAmine [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues? Are you *sure* the data in your structures are correct? How do you *read* the or initialize your structures?

Comment: I have functions that allow me to see the elf header's elements ("data" here), and it's all correct, that's why i am sure that the problem is when i try to write this header.

Comment: @TaguiAmine And you remembered to fix the second issue I mention (about `sizeof`) as well?